# how to get userid from supabase default table react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, supabase-database, supabase-js

in my mobile app I have a userinfo table witch has a primary key that references the default user table in supabase now when trying to sign up i can insert into user_info because I cant get the id from auth.users

```
const handlesignup = async () => {
try {
  
  let { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });

  if (error) {
    console.log('Sign up error:', error.message);
    return;
  }

  const {user1, error3 } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });

  if (error3) {
    console.log('Sign in error:', error3.message);
    return;
  }

  const userId = user1?.id;

  
  const { data, error: insertError } = await supabase
    .from('user_info')
    .insert([
      {
        name: name,
        lname: lname,
        id: userId,
      },
    ]);

  if (insertError) {
    console.log('Insert error:', insertError.message);
    return;
  }

 
  console.log('Sign up successful!');
  console.log('User ID:', userId);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error.message);
}
```

};

how do i get the userid to insert into the user_info table so they can be linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the data returned from the login and that's how i accessed it

```
 const handlesignup = async () => {
try {
  let { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });

  if (error) {
    console.log('Sign up error:', error.message);
    return;
  }

  const { data, error:error2 } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  })

  if (error2) {
    console.log('Sign in error:', error2.message);
    return;
  }

  
  const userId = data.user.id;
  
  //console.log('userId:', data.user);

  
  const { data1, error: insertError } = await supabase
    .from('user_info')
    .insert([
      {
        name: name,
        lname: lname,
        id: userId,
      },
    ]);

  if (insertError) {
    console.log('Insert error:', insertError.message);
    return;
  }

  navigation.navigate('User-home');
  //console.log('Sign up successful!');
  //console.log('User ID:', userId);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error.message);
}
```

};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).